# Angular js avoid dupilicate data when users Infinite scroll & remove dom elements for Previous data

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, json

am working on Angular-js Infinite scroll(with out jquery) i want to show first 3 data in on-load and when user scroll it loads next 3 data from the array j-son object.the issue is, i can load the first 3 data in on-load,but in scroll it loads again first 3 data instead of showing next 3 data.And also if user scroll down for next set of data  it should show the data meanwhile if user scroll up mans show the previous set of data (concept based on pagination).

Following array used to parse the data in controller :

```js
var app = angular.module('Demo', []);

app.controller('VerticleDemo', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.Arr = [{
    "Select": "11",
    "PhotoCount": "12"
  }, {
    "Select": "21",
    "PhotoCount": "22"
  }, {
    "Select": "31",
    "PhotoCount": "32"
  }, {
    "Select": "1",
    "PhotoCount": "1"
  }, {
    "Select": "71",
    "PhotoCount": "72"
  }, {
    "Select": "441",
    "PhotoCount": "90"
  }, ];

  $scope.addItems = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      $scope.items.push($scope.Arr[i]);

    }
  };


  $scope.addItems();
});
```

```css
    .scroll-loader {
      background: #f7f7f7;
      height: 90px;
      border: 3px solid #d2d2d2;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      overflow: auto;
      padding: 10px 0;
      border-radius: .5rem 0 0 .5rem;
    }
    .scroll-loader li {
      list-style: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
```

i Don't know how to eliminate the duplicate data.And also i tried different ways to avoid this issue.js-fiddle link is given below:
https://jsfiddle.net/sathishkti/96qhssfe/15/
help out from this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `addItems()`:

You are always adding item 0 to 3, what you want to do is create an offSet variable that will skip the items that have already been displayed. You can increment this by `X` everytime your scroll is instantiated. For ease of use I have stored the number 3 in a variable. However I would recommend making it part of the directive, so that you can set it on the html element for flexibility.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('tstrll', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.Arr = [{
    "Select": "11",
    "PhotoCount": "12"
  }, {
    "Select": "21",
    "PhotoCount": "22"
  }, {
    "Select": "31",
    "PhotoCount": "32"
  }, {
    "Select": "1",
    "PhotoCount": "1"
  }, {
    "Select": "71",
    "PhotoCount": "72"
  }, {
    "Select": "441",
    "PhotoCount": "90"
  }, ];

  $scope.numberOfItems = 3;
  $scope.offSet = 0; //save the offset.
  $scope.addItems = function() {
    if ($scope.offSet <= $scope.Arr.length) //make sure it stops when there are NO new elements.
    {
      //increase the loop to match the offset to grab new values
      for (var i = $scope.offSet; i < $scope.offSet + $scope.numberOfItems; i++) {

        $scope.items.push($scope.Arr[i]);

      }
        $scope.offSet += $scope.numberOfItems; //increment the offset by 3.
    }
  };


  $scope.addItems();
});


    app.directive('infiniteScroll', [ "$window", function ($window) {
        return {
            link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var offset = parseInt(attrs.threshold) || 0;
                var e = element[0];

                element.bind('scroll', function () {
                    if (e.scrollTop + e.offsetHeight >= e.scrollHeight - offset) {
                        scope.$apply(attrs.infiniteScroll);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/96qhssfe/17/)